# Clear JS - Metaplex is not a constructor

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, metaplex-js, js

I am trying to construct new Metaplex with connection, but I am getting error

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Metaplex is not defined
```

My code:

```
<h1>Moralis API Response:</h1>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/spl-token@0.1.8/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@metaplex/js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (async () => {
  const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
  const keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();

  const metaplex2 = new Metaplex(connection);
})();
</script>
```

Also tried

```
const metaplex2 = new metaplex.Metaplex(connection);
```

But problem is the same

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to compile your code to an ES module or CJS for compatibility. I found out recently that I have to do this to make Metaplex work in the browser. Check out [tsup](https://github.com/egoist/tsup) for a tool that helps with that.